# What are the default display of dom elements?

Tags: html, css, dom

Does exist a website with a list of default display of dom elements?

For example:

- Block: div, p, etc
- inline: span, b, etc

Answer (score 5):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Should still be reasonably accurate

```
html, address,
blockquote,
body, dd, div,
dl, dt, fieldset, form,
frame, frameset,
h1, h2, h3, h4,
h5, h6, noframes,
ol, p, ul, center,
dir, hr, menu, pre   { display: block; unicode-bidi: embed }
li              { display: list-item }
head            { display: none }
table           { display: table }
tr              { display: table-row }
thead           { display: table-header-group }
tbody           { display: table-row-group }
tfoot           { display: table-footer-group }
col             { display: table-column }
colgroup        { display: table-column-group }
td, th          { display: table-cell }
caption         { display: table-caption }
th              { font-weight: bolder; text-align: center }
caption         { text-align: center }
body            { margin: 8px }
h1              { font-size: 2em; margin: .67em 0 }
h2              { font-size: 1.5em; margin: .75em 0 }
h3              { font-size: 1.17em; margin: .83em 0 }
h4, p,
blockquote, ul,
fieldset, form,
ol, dl, dir,
menu            { margin: 1.12em 0 }
h5              { font-size: .83em; margin: 1.5em 0 }
h6              { font-size: .75em; margin: 1.67em 0 }
h1, h2, h3, h4,
h5, h6, b,
strong          { font-weight: bolder }
blockquote      { margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px }
i, cite, em,
var, address    { font-style: italic }
pre, tt, code,
kbd, samp       { font-family: monospace }
pre             { white-space: pre }
button, textarea,
input, select   { display: inline-block }
big             { font-size: 1.17em }
small, sub, sup { font-size: .83em }
sub             { vertical-align: sub }
sup             { vertical-align: super }
table           { border-spacing: 2px; }
thead, tbody,
tfoot           { vertical-align: middle }
td, th, tr      { vertical-align: inherit }
s, strike, del  { text-decoration: line-through }
hr              { border: 1px inset }
ol, ul, dir,
menu, dd        { margin-left: 40px }
ol              { list-style-type: decimal }
ol ul, ul ol,
ul ul, ol ol    { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0 }
u, ins          { text-decoration: underline }
br:before       { content: "\A"; white-space: pre-line }
center          { text-align: center }
:link, :visited { text-decoration: underline }
:focus          { outline: thin dotted invert }

/* Begin bidirectionality settings (do not change) */
BDO[DIR="ltr"]  { direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: bidi-override }
BDO[DIR="rtl"]  { direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override }

*[DIR="ltr"]    { direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: embed }
*[DIR="rtl"]    { direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed }

@media print {
  h1            { page-break-before: always }
  h1, h2, h3,
  h4, h5, h6    { page-break-after: avoid }
  ul, ol, dl    { page-break-before: avoid }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find them on **Mozilla**:

From here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML, you can access links like these:

- [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente)
- [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Answer (score 1):

The default value of the `display` property for an element is browser-dependent. It may also depend on the type of the element, especially for the rather polymorphic `input` element.

In practice, though, browsers behave in rather similar ways. There are differences mostly with elements that can be characterized as “replaced elements” from the CSS perspective, i.e. their rendering is not fully determined and controllable with CSS but may depend on browser internals and on things like plugins.

The defaults are being standardized in HTML5, where the [Rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#rendering) section describes the “expected rendering”, including default values for `display`. Note that the *initial* value of `display` is `inline`, so if the expected rendering does not specify a `display` value, `display: inline` is “expected”. Specifying “expected rendering” is technically not normative, but rather close.